# How to set SQL Server database connection timeout and query timeout in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to set database connection timeout and query timeout

Here is my code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement;

public class CreateConnection {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databasename=test";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "root";
    try {

        SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
        ds.setUser("root");
        ds.setPassword("root@123");
        ds.setServerName("localhost");
        ds.setPortNumber(1433);
        ds.setDatabaseName("test");
        ds.setQueryTimeout(1);
        ds.setCancelQueryTimeout(1);
        ds.setLoginTimeout(1); // Connection timeout is not working
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
        DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(1);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        ((SQLServerDataSource) conn).setCancelQueryTimeout(1);


        if (conn != null) {
            DatabaseMetaData dm = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("Driver name: " + dm.getDriverName());
            System.out.println("Driver version: " + dm.getDriverVersion());
            System.out.println("Product name: " + dm.getDatabaseProductName());
            System.out.println("Product version: " + dm.getDatabaseProductVersion());
        }

        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.setQueryTimeout(1);
        ((SQLServerStatement) statement).setCancelQueryTimeout(1);
        
        System.out.println("get query stmnt----"+statement.getQueryTimeout());
        System.out.println("get query ds---"+ds.getQueryTimeout());
        System.out.println("get connection logintimeout ds---"+ds.getLoginTimeout());
        System.out.println("get getCancelQueryTimeout ds----"+ds.getCancelQueryTimeout());

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM emp");
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.print(rs.getString("PersonID") + " \t");
            System.out.println(rs.getString("FirstName"));
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: And, what is or isn't working about your code?

Comment: Thank for the reply, Yes i added **ds.setLoginTimeout(int sec);** for Connection timeout -------

        **ds.setQueryTimeout(1);**
        **ds.setCancelQueryTimeout(1);** for query time out  both are not working in my case